# How can I change Outlined Button icon programmatically?

Tags: android, button, material-design

https://material.io/develop/android/components/buttons#text-button
From this reference there is a setIcon method but how can I reach it?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are not using material theme as your app theme, you need to declare Material button like this in xml:

```
 <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                android:id="@+id/outlinedButton"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Outlined button"
                app:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_background"
                style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton.Icon"
                />
```

And to change icon programmatically:

```
findViewById<MaterialButton>(R.id.outlinedButton).setIcon(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground))
```

Comment: Thanks. 
I use my own theme but the parent is Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar however this is not enough, I need to use what you said.

Comment: I upvoted wrongly! This is not working for me!

Answer (score 1):

In Android, every UI widget component is either a [`View`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View), or derives from the `View`, and according to the documentation, the [`Button`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button) is derived from `TextView`.

Now there is something important to know about the texts in Android. The framework lets you define the `Compound Drawables` for every text -  take a look at [this method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)). With it you can set the compound drawables programmatically, but note also the `Related XML Attributes` section of the docs - the drawables can be defined in XML, which is usually the simplest way (if applicable in a given case of course).

The button image you attached looks like [`MaterialButton`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton) which is also a standard `Button`, so the 'plus' icon should just be a compound drawable and as such should be easily changeable, just as described above.

EDIT: on second thoughts, things aren't often that simple with the Google's material design library for Android. Take a look at the `MaterialButton` docs I have linked above - there is a [`setIcon()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/material/button/MaterialButton#seticon) method there and it probably answers your question. You can also define your icon drawable in XML, using `app:icon` attribute.